# PhpWord , templateProcessor and setMacroChars

Tags: phpword

With the latest version of phpWord, is it possible to change the macro characters with the `setMacroChars` method? The default macro characters are `${` and `}`, but I've tried many combinations and only the default pattern works:

```php
$templateProcessor = new TemplateProcessor($localWordFileName);
$templateProcessor->setMacroChars('{#', '}');
```

Has anyone managed to change these macro characters?